# ui:param not working when f:metaData is present

Tags: jsf, facelets

I'm using JSF 2.1 and I want to pass a parameter to a custom tag that records the url and the page title using `ui:param` to the tag. This works fine, but if there is a `f:metadata` section no data is passed, i.d. the `dynamicBreadCrumb.addItem()` from the template is not called during the `preRenderView`.

This is the page using a template

```
<ui:param name="tilte" value="#{msg['PAGE_HEADER.ORDER']}"/>


<!--  when this is within the page, the title param is not passed on  -->
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="orderNumber"
                 value="#{editOrder.model.orderNumber}"/>
</f:metadata>

... and so on
```

This is the custom tag

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<ui:param name="page" value="#{page}"/>
<ui:param name="param" value="#{paramValues}"/>
<h:form id="history" >
    <h:outputText value="#{msg['COMMON.HISTORY_BAR']}" />
    <ul id="last-actions-list">
        <ui:repeat value="#{dynamicHistoryBean.items}" var="item">
            <li><a href="#{item.href}">#{item.title}</a></li>
        </ui:repeat>
    </ul>
</h:form>
```

This is the template

```
<ui:param name="title" value="#{title}"/>
<ui:param name="param" value="#{paramValues}"/>

<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{dynamicHistoryBean.addHistoryItem(title,param)}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Comment: I see many `<ui:param` but no token which can use an `<ui:param` like `<ui:composition template=...` , `<ui:insert` , `<ui:decorate` or `ui:include`

Comment: I guess you want to reuse the custom tag? Then implement it as a composite component. You're completely linking your custom tag to this specific use case. This way: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html BTW, I wouldn't recommend you embedding a form tag in the composite component. `h:form` tags are not nestable and you can always declare it outside the component.